# How to insert an "info" node into a linked-list, numerically or alphabetically, without using a sorting method?

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes

I have to create a method that inserts information numerically but, the problem specifically says not to use a sorting method.

The list should always be sorted by rfidTagNumber. However, this doesn't mean you run a sorting algorithm on the list. As you insert each info into the sorted list, traverse the list to figure out where the new info should go and insert there. Then the new list is still sorted without running a sorting algorithm.

Also, I have a node that has multiple components. How can I make one node greater than the other based on one component such as price. (Price is one of the components)

I'm new to linked lists so I'm struggling here..

Thanks guys

```
if (head == null) // if the list is empty then you can just put the info in the first link
            head = temp = cursor = null;
        else { //other options
            while (temp != null)

                for (temp = head; temp.next != null; temp = temp.next );
                    if ( temp > temp.prev && temp < temp.next )
                        temp = temp.next;
        }
```

^ this is what I have right now. Its full of errors but what I want to do is pretty much say that if a node is greater than the previous and less than the next one then, insert here.

How can I implement this and how can I make the RFDNumber the metric in which the computer decides whether or not a node is greater than another.

Comment: I have no idea where to start. I'm having trouble setting up a way to make one node greater than another based on one component in the node (the price).

Comment: start by creating a comparator for the data

Comment: Maybe `List` is not best data structure for your needs ? Can you explain what are you going to do with this information after inserting ?

Answer (score 0):

Just start at the beginning of the list and at each step compare your rfidTagNumber to number for the next node. If it is less than or equal to that node's number, insert the new node after the current node.

If you give each node a public `rfidTagNumber` member, you can reference it directly in your conditional. Also, your function should have two parameters: a head node `head` that refers to the start of the list, and a node you want to insert, let's call it `insertNode`.

Given these two values, let's change the conditional of your function a bit. You do not want to compare `insertNode` to the previous and next node, you want to compare it to the *current* and next node. So instead of:

```
if ( temp > temp.prev && temp < temp.next )
```

We'd do something like:

```
if ( insertNode.rfidTagNumber >= temp.rfidTagNumber && insertNode.rfidTagNumber <= temp.next.rfidTagNumber )
```

If this condition is true then you want to insert your node here. This involves changing `next` for the current node and `prev` for the next node. Here we also need to properly assign `prev` and `next` for `insertNode`. We can do this with the following code:

```
insertNode.prev = current
insertNode.next = current.next
current.next.prev = insertNode
current.next = insertNode
```

Keep in mind the order of these statements matters as you do not want to modify `current.next` without first storing a reference to it in `insertNode.next`.

Comment: Thanks so how would I go about writing something like "if the rfdnumber in the node is less than the node I am at and greater than the node than I just passed ..... insert here"